# Remove space from a list object while iterating using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is my code , which is returning spaces along with some valid strings. But, my requirement is to invalidate space and collect only strings

```
List<String> stateCodes = stateList.stream()
                                    .map(state-> physician.getStateDetails().getStateCode())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When I print stateCodes, it returns

```
[ ,  , 197, 148,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```

Here I require only [197,148]

Comment: Use the filter method to only return those elements that fit your needs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter out the empty values. I'm not sure if those are empty `String`s in your output. If they are, you can filter them out with:

```
List<String> stateCodes =
    stateList.stream()
             .map(state-> physician.getStateDetails().getStateCode())
             .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Note*: you can add `trim()` (to either the `map` or `filter` steps) to filter out `String`s which contain only white spaces:

```
List<String> stateCodes =
    stateList.stream()
             .map(state-> physician.getStateDetails().getStateCode().trim())
             .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Good answer. Only one doubt if  `physician.getStateDetails().getStateCode()` have a space.

Comment: Sudhir, use StringUtils.IsNotEmpty

Comment: @SudhirOjha in that case, you have to change the filter Predicate to something like `s -> !s.trim().isEmpty()`

Comment: No need to `trim()` in `.map(....)` or remove it from `filter(...)`

Comment: @HadiJ I missed that change, which was another user's edit. You are correct.

Comment: Or `filter(String::isBlank)` from Java11

Comment: @Syed I edited my answer. The second snippet will take care of filtering out white-space only Strings. If you are using Java 11 or above, you can use YCF_L suggestion as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You should [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) the strings first, after that filter by [isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) and collect.

Answer (score 0):

I will do:

```
List<String> stateCodes =
stateList.stream()
         .map(state-> physician.getStateDetails().getStateCode())
         .filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- I add a filter on data and remove the empty data - used trim only in predicate.